# Android app architecture - Separate code and database layers

Tags: android, performance, web-services, rest, architecture

I'm writing an Android app which does the following:

1. Get data from the server.
2. Save the data to the database.
3. Refresh the views with the data from the database.

In my previous apps, I used to write service calls using Ion and then do the DB call using ORMLite and refresh the views. The whole code was residing in the appropriate Activity or Fragment.

This results in a lot of repeating and redundant code.

Can you please recommend how to separate out these layers.

Thanks

PS: I have ideas how to do it, but that necessitates passing around the context and increased complexity of callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for your requirements is to follow a design pattern and i recommend MVP design pattern.
Find the below link to know how to implement MVP design pattern

http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/

Comment: It takes care of decoupling the binding from the view, but segregated network calls in one class will require multiple listeners ...